# URL.Action appends extra information to parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my view, I have the following code:

```
@foreach (Document document in Model.Documents)
{
  <img src="@Url.Action("GetDocument", new { docId = Model.DocId, filename =  
  document.DocumentName })" />
}
```

Stepping through the code, the filename resolves as expected, to "clown.jpg".

However, when this parameter is passed to the controller like so:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[OutputCache(Duration = 36000)]
public virtual ImageResult GetDocument(int docId, string filename)
    {
        var attachment = _docService.GetDocument(docId, filename);
        ...........
    }
```

The filename parameter has extra integers appended to it, so its value is something like "clown.jpg?316767349393".

Why is that, and how to I make it not do that? It is stopping me from looking up the file by filename. I could just hack my way around this by ignoring everything from the ? onward, but I want to know why this is happening and the correct method for stopping it from happening.

EDIT: I've worked around this by adding this line of code in the controller:

```
filename = filename.Split('?')[0];
```

But obviously that's not really how I want to be coding this...

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with caching.

Comment: If I understand your route, it should generate a url like "getdocument/?docId=1234567&filename=test", correct? Is that happening correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, Nick. But what I'm actually getting is something like "getdocument/?docId=1234567&filename=test?1336848484832".

Comment: Why haven't you specified the "VaryByParam" option? You're telling the action to cache regardless of the parameters. You need VaryByParam="docId;filename". Does the raw HTML generated have the "?#############" or is it possible that you're using a jQuery plugin that is appending a timestamp to prevent caching?

Comment: In ImageResult GetDocument( <- you have int docIdId instead of docId, is that normal?

Comment: That's just a typo. I've fixed it, thanks.  Nick, thanks for the suggestions. I'll look into the VaryByParam option, I'm new to MVC so I'm not familiar with that one.